# Why Facebook Pixel doesn't track URLs when embedded in iframe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

I've noticed that when FB pixel is embedded into a standard web page, it works correctly.
This is the call it does:

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=PIXEL_ID&ev=PageView&
dl=https%3A%2F%2Fautotarget.co%2Fauto%2Faudi%2Fa6%2Fpr%2Femilia-romagna%2F-8-%2F48%2F&rl=&if=false&ts=1464110706891&v=2.5.0&pv=visible
```

And i see the url on the Audicence panel on Business Manager.

The problem is when the FB pixel is embedded on iframes. It seems it doesn't track the iframe URL.
This is the call it does:

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=PIXEL_ID&ev=PageView&
dl=https%3A%2F%2Fautotarget.co%2Fauto%2Faudi%2Fa6%2Fpr%2Femilia-romagna%2F-8-%2F48%2Fthankyou-call%2F&
rl=https%3A%2F%2Fautotarget.co%2Fauto%2Faudi%2Fa6%2Fpr%2Femilia-romagna%2F-8-%2F48%2F&
if=true&ts=1464107424477&v=2.5.0&pv=visible
```

In this case **dl** parameter is the right URL, **rl** parameter is the URL of the page embedding the iframe.

Could you please help us?